# How to Separate PHP Object

Tags: php

I am confused on how to separate the following output into separate variables. Here is the array I am working with:

```
stdClass Object ( [FlightInfoExResult] => stdClass Object ( [next_offset] => 1 [flights] => stdClass Object ( [faFlightID] => UAL1-1489818347-airline-0169 [ident] => UAL1 [aircrafttype] => B789 [filed_ete] => 17:05:00 [filed_time] => 1489818347 [filed_departuretime] => 1490074200 [filed_airspeed_kts] => 430 [filed_airspeed_mach] => [filed_altitude] => 0 [route] => [actualdeparturetime] => 0 [estimatedarrivaltime] => 1490136300 [actualarrivaltime] => 0 [diverted] => [origin] => KSFO [destination] => WSSS [originName] => San Francisco Intl [originCity] => San Francisco, CA [destinationName] => Singapore Changi [destinationCity] => Singapore ) ) )
```

I am outputting this through the FlightAware API system. Here is the code I am using to output the above:

```
$params = array("ident" => "UAL1","howMany" => 1,"offset" => 0 );
$result = $client->FlightInfoEx($params);
print_r($result);
```

Here is an example of how I would like it to seperate the object:

```
 UAL1,B789 ect.
```

Comment: How do you want to separate? Could you provide an example of what your resulting values would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all that's not an array your working with, it is an object.

To access it's properties use the `->` syntax, i.e.

```
$flightInfoExResult = $result->FlightInfoExResult;
```

You can then access the `next_offset` property with

`flightInfoExResult->next_offset;` and so on.